# Using an android-library with gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, import, android-studio, google-play-services, libraries

I've been trying to do get the gamebaseutil into my project.. I switched from eclipse to android studios 'cause it seemed impossible to import it in Eclipse.. Now I don't understand  the importing of android studios very well so I'm still trying to import and use it..I have really no idea what i do wrong or what i have to do... I'm pretty sure I imported GameBaseUtil into android studios but now I want to make use of it in my project.. I have added  " include '(:libraries):BaseGameUtils', ':Name' " to my settings.gradle.. and when I run it, there are no gradle build errors but still I can't instantiate  "GameHelper mHelper;" for example. Or "extends GameBaseActivity"

Please tell me what to do. I'm really desperate 'cause I have been reading and trying the whole day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the lib in gradle.settings is the first step.

The next step is to add the lib as a dependency of your main project (in the **build.gradle**):

If you have the sources of the library :

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':GameBaseUtil')
    ...
}
```

If your library is in a maven repository :

```
dependencies {
    compile '<groupid>:<artifactid>:<version>'
    ...
}
```

there other ways to define a dependency : [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html)

Comment: Yes I know the source of the Library. Do I have to put the source in the place of :GameBaseUtil'? 'Cause otherwise I get this error: Error:(27, 0) Project with path ':GameBaseUtil' could not be found in project ':'.

Comment: In the .idea/modules.xml I find this filepath:<module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/(/libraries)/BaseGameUtils/BaseGameUtils.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/(/libraries)/BaseGameUtils/BaseGameUtils.iml" />

But still no success..